# setting migration magento 1.9.1.0 to magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrating settings from Magento 1 to Magento 2, I ran the migration setting commands and I've got a successful message.
The problem is that when I navigate to the website I get this error:

```
Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in /var/www/vhosts/myhost/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreRepository.php:112 Stack trace: #0....
```

command:

```
php -f bin/magento migrate:settings -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

Comment: which command you execute ??